# How I can change 2sxc admin or editor to spanish

Tags: 2sxc

I would like to change all editor options to spanish for administrators.

I found language pack but honestly I don´t know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this should be easy to get started with. If you are on a modern version of Dnn, go to Settings, Site Settings, then the Languages tab.

Click on "+ Add New Language" then select your best language choice from the existing Language dropdown. Then Save.

After that try testing things out. You may want to carefully review the rest of the settings under Languages also to make sure it is doing what you are expecting.

Comment: Hi Jeremy I already changed language in DNN and everything is being showed in Spanish except 2sxc.  I think doesn’t have resources for that language

Comment: My bad, I somehow overlooked "2sxc" in the title. You'll need to wait and see if Daniel or someone else chimes in. There is a way to do it manually, but I would guess that someone has already done this somewhere and its an easy thing to find/add/install/etc. Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The edit-UI has not been translated to spanish yet, but we would be super-happy if you could do this!

There are some instructions https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/help-translate-2sxc-in-less-than-one-hour but they are probably outdated.

If you plan to volunteer, it will take you ca. 2-3 hours. Best open an issue on Github and we'll guide you through it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Count on that, on the next days i will translate the files and send to you. Thanks for the information